# Find stored procedure that references multiple specific tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the SQL that I am using:

```
select distinct 
    [Table Name] = o.Name, [Found In] = sp.Name, sp.type_desc
from 
    sys.objects o 
inner join 
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sd on o.object_id = sd.referenced_id
inner join 
    sys.objects sp on sd.referencing_id = sp.object_id
                    and sp.type in ('P', 'FN')
where 
    o.name = 'PacManPackage' and o.name = 'PacManCompanyPackage'
order by 
    sp.Name
```

If I remove the o.name and view with only one table it works. But I need to find stored procedures that reference a few different tables (but they must reference all of them)

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: How can "o.name 'PacManPackage' and o.name = 'PacManCompanyPackage'" both be true?

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to find stored procedures or scalar functions that reference all of a set of tables? How about this for a quick and dirty answer;

```
select
    sp.name
from
    sys.objects sp
        inner join sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed on sed.referencing_id = sp.object_id
            inner join sys.objects t on t.object_id = sed.referenced_id
                                    and t.type = 'U'

where 
    sp.type in ('P', 'FN')
    and t.name in ('PacManPackage', 'PacManCompanyPackage')
group by
    sp.name
having 
    count(*) = 2 -- change accordingly
```